# How to load extjs 4 grid data on form submission?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am new to ExtJS.

I am developing a page which has a form at the top and a grid below.  When user enters the search criteria in the form and enters Submit, grid has to be populated with data accordingly.

I have managed to get the JSON data from server to the client

```
console.log('response.responseText');
```

prints the data correctly, but unable to assign that to the grid.

Here is my code

```
Ext.define('colModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.ColumnModel',
    fields: [
             'personId',
             'country',
             'idType',
             'idValue'
             ]
});

// create the data store
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'colModel',
    fields: [
       {name: 'personId'},
       {name: 'country'},
       {name: 'idType'},
       {name: 'idValue'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'person'
        }
    },

    autoLoad: false,

});
 // create the Grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    stateful: true,
    id: 'myGrid',
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            text     : 'Person Id',
            flex     : 1,
            sortable : false,
            dataIndex: 'personId'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Country',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,               
            dataIndex: 'country'
        },
        {
            text     : 'ID Type',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'idType'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Id Value',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'idValue'
        },            
    ],        
    height: 350,
    title: 'Array Grid',
    renderTo: 'bottom',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        ForceFit: true,
        loadMask:false
    }
});
```

and this function get invoked after form submission and response returned from server

```
displayGrid : function(response, opts) {
                    //Received response from the server
                    console.log('On Success');
                    responseData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    console.log('response success ',responseData);
                    console.log(Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore());
                    grid.getStore().loadData('colModel',false);
            }
```

I have managed to populate grid data on page load using the following code

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
                        model: 'colModel',

                        proxy: {
                            type: 'rest',
                            url : 'PersonSearch',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'person'
                            }
                        },
                        autoLoad: true                       
                    });
```

but failed to load grid data on form submission.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using ExtJS 4.2

**Update**

This is the JSON update, I am getting from the server(caught using Firefox Browser Console)

```
 "{"person":[{"personId":"1","country":"country 1","idType":"idType 1","idValue":"idValue 1"},{"personId":"2","country":"country 2","idType":"idType 2","idValue":"idValue 2"},{"personId":"3","country":"country 3","idType":"idType 3","idValue":"idValue 3"},{"personId":"4","country":"country 4","idType":"idType 4","idValue":"idValue 4"},{"personId":"5","country":"country 5","idType":"idType 5","idValue":"idValue 5"}]}
```

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used **forgivenson** comment and set autoLoad: true

and

Updated the displayGrid method as below

```
displayGrid : function(response, opts) {
                    //Received response from the server
                    console.log('On Success');
                    responseData = Ext.decode(response.responseText,false);
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                    grid.getStore().loadData(responseData.person);
            }
```

and the grid gets populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually loading the data. Your data is stored in `responseData`, so your `loadData` call should load that data into the store. So, your `loadData` call should be as follows:

```
grid.getStore().loadData(responseData);
```

Note that this assumes that your `responseData` is in the correct format for the store you are loading it into. (Also note that the second parameter is false by default, so it isn't necessary to include it in this case)

Comment: I addded, but no change in grid:(

Comment: Since you have the store configured with a proxy, you could just call `grid.getStore().load()` to load data using the proxy (like when you set `autoload: true`). If you need to filter the data loaded based on values submitted in the form, then you should set up filters via extjs (either local filters or remote filters).

Comment: updated as you suggested, still the grid is not getting populated.  I have added JSON response from server in the question for your reference.

Comment: got answer in different direction which I didn't expect.  Your comment autoload: true helped though.